# Defining absolute text size using lattice

Tags: r, lattice, trellis

I am trying to get figures ready for publication, where the journal requires the figures to be a certain width and height and the font size to be 10.

This is my basic structure:

```
cairo_ps(file = "plot.eps", width = 6.85, height = 9.213)
dotplot(...)
dev.off()
```

I've tried to force the font size using `trellis.par.set`, `trellis.device` and setting it with `pointsize` in the device itself, but no luck. I can't get to change the font size to be anything than it defaults to. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you set the font size using Cairo? It also hase a pointsize argument.

Comment: I did. Read my question carefully.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducable data example so to check and see what you already did? With a minimal example, I can reproduce this behavior, meaning that lattice graphics are not affected by changes if `pointsize` made in the graphics device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Cairo` instead. This solution can, however, yield some unexpected results as it seems, for example when changing the `dpi` argument when calling `Cairo`.

There seems to be some coding problems involved. For example, I have to re-run the code after changing the font size for changes to take effect. Be warned! You might have to tweak it a bit to get the font size you want.

Contrary to the built-in graphics devices, however, this seems to react to changes made by `trellis.par.set`. Here is a example with PNG, the same works for me with PDF:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3)

Cairo(file = "plot.png", type="png", units="in", width = 6, height = 3, dpi=100)
xyplot(b~a, dat) 
trellis.par.set("fontsize", list(text=12, points=8)) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Compare to:

```
Cairo(file = "plot.png", type="png", units="in", width = 6, height = 3, dpi=100)
xyplot(b~a, dat) 
trellis.par.set("fontsize", list(text=18, points=8)) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Is `Cairo()` from the similarly named package?

Comment: Yes, the package and the "generic" function are both named `Cairo`. There are also output-specific devices `CairoPDF()` etc. but `Cairo()` is the generic interface.

Comment: Works! Seems like my problem was with `trellis.par.set`. If you put it before the plotting command, you don't have to re-run it twice. Once I got that right, `cairo_ps()` did the work. It does seem however that `Cairo()` is a bit more convenient than `cairo_ps()`.

Comment: Ha, did NOT think of that. Glad it could still help a bit!

Comment: One last thing, for some reason `Cairo()` does not work that well and occasionally spits out errors. On the other hand, `CairoPS()` works just fine!